# Scraping webpages for links with a specific class

Tags: hyperlink, beautifulsoup, scrape

First post here and I have had a look but can't find the answer I need.

I'm trying to go through a website and find all the links that have a certain class, in this case 'annmt'.

I want the result to only show the link though and am having trouble trying to get the format right. Once right I want to append it to an empty list that I can call on later.

My code is:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import datetime as dt

    l = []

    def getlinks():
        page = requests.get("http://www.investegate.co.uk/Index.aspx?
        ftse=1&date=20170609")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        for links in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'annmt'}):
            for link in links.find_all('a', href=True):
                link = link['href']
                l.append(link)
        print l
```

Comment: Apologies for the format. The code does have the correct indentation in practice, but I pasted it in poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for your reference:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime as dt

l = []

def getlinks():
    page = requests.get("http://www.investegate.co.uk/Index.aspx?ftse=1&date=20170609")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    for links in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'annmt'}):
        link = links.get('href')
        l.append(link)
    print l
```